# Private Setters in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I have been looking but couldn't find any reference to this. I would like to create a private setter in Dart to call an additional function after I have changed a private variable.

```
ViewState _state;

ViewState get state => _state;

set _state(value) {
  _state = value;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

How Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the private setter, just the choices of naming.

Just as you couldnt use `state` as the name of the variable because it was the name of the getter, you cant use `_state` for the variable and setter.

It is kind of ugly but using `__state` for your variable (and updating the getter and setter accordingly) should get the job done.

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, the name `__state` is not important, it just needs to be a name that is not taken by the getter/setter. Variable `_myState` with getter `state` and setter `_state` works just as well.

Comment: nice workaround. The double underscore is not something I'd like to teach, but your answer did solve the problem. I think I'll stick to a _setState() method call. Thanks, this will be helpful

Comment: You don't have to use double-underscores.  As long as you name your underlying variable something else (e.g. `_rawState`) it should work.  That said, having a setter without a getter of the same name is unusual, and I think a separate `_setState` method would be clearer.

Answer (score 11):

Dart is no allowing private setters, it's true. You can hack it with your own private function

```
ViewState _state;

ViewState get state => _state;

void _changeState(value) {
  _state = value;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

here my sample on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/dac9315bdee85ae129ba90ee69de64c5) where you can make some experiments.

Comment: I am doing this already but I wanted use the equals operator to set the value and perform additional logic. The answer above gave a work around

Comment: The problem is that the analyzer will complain with this: Use a setter for operations that conceptually change a property.dartuse_setters_to_change_properties